Handling null value in response, using axios and mongoose schema
When doing getOrder, it returns a response of user:null. Because of this, my database is full of orders without user names. What I want is to display the user's _id in the newly created order when getOrder runs.
const getOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log("Request received:", req.params.id);  // Log the request parameters
        const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id)
            .populate("user", "-password -isAdmin -_id -__v -createdAt -updatedAt")
            .orFail();
        console.log("Order found:", order);  // Log the retrieved order
        
        res.send(order);  // Send the order in the response
        console.log("Order sent in response:", order);  // Log confirmation that the order was sent

    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", err.message);  // Log the error message
        next(err);  // Pass the error to the next middleware
    }
}; 

I am calling this getOrder in the OrderDetails component.
import UserOrderDetailsPageComponent from "./components/UserOrderDetailsPageComponent";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL || 'http://localhost:5000';


const getOrder = async (orderId) => {
  const {data} = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/api/orders/user/` + orderId);
  console.log("get orderrr",data);
  return data;
}



const updateOrder = async (orderId) => {
  const {data} = await axios.put(`${apiUrl}/api/orders/paid/`+ orderId, );
  return data;
}

  const UserOrderDetailsPage = () => {
    const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userRegisterLogin.userInfo);

    const getUser = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/api/users/profile/` + userInfo._id);
     
      return data;
    }

    return <UserOrderDetailsPageComponent 
    userInfo={userInfo}
    getUser={getUser}
    getOrder={getOrder}
    updateOrder={updateOrder}
    />
  }
  
  export default UserOrderDetailsPage;
  
  

  
  

I thought that user cannot be fetched, but it is not so. 
When createOrder is executed, I thought it was originally returning order user:null, but when I do console.log, it returns user: 625add3d78fb449f9d9fe2ee which I want.
const createOrder = async (req, res,next) => {
    try {
        const {cartItems, orderTotal, paymentMethod} = req.body;
        if(!cartItems || !orderTotal || !paymentMethod){
            return res.status(400).send("All inputs are required");
        }

        let ids = cartItems.map((item)=> {
            return item.productID;
        })
        let qty = cartItems.map((item)=> {
            return Number(item.quantity);
        })

        await Product.find({_id: { $in: ids }}).then((products)=>{
            products.forEach(function(product, idx){
                product.sales += qty[idx];
                product.save();
            })
        })

        const order = new Order({
            user: new ObjectId(req.user._id),
            orderTotal: orderTotal,
            cartItems: cartItems,
            paymentMethod: paymentMethod
        })
        const createdOrder = await order.save();
        res.status(201).send(createdOrder);
        console.log("created order:",createdOrder)

    }  catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
 

here is getOrder log:

     useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrderDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getOrder( id);

        
        console.log("Order Data user: ", data);

        // Set the necessary state based on the fetched order data
        setPaymentMethod(data.paymentMethod);
        setCartItems(data.cartItems);
        setCartSubtotal(data.orderTotal.cartSubtotal);

        if (data.user) {
          setUserAddress({
            address: data.user.address,
            city: data.user.city,
            country: data.user.country,
            zipCode: data.user.zipCode,
            state: data.user.state,
            phoneNumber: data.user.phoneNumber,
          });
        } 

        setIsDelivered(data.isDelivered ? data.deliveredAt : false);
        setIsPaid(data.isPaid ? data.paidAt : false);

        if (data.isPaid) {
          setOrderButtonMessage("Захиалга амжилттай боллоо.");
          setButtonDisabled(true);
        } else {
          if (data.paymentMethod === "pp") {
            setOrderButtonMessage("Pay for your order");
          } else if (data.paymentMethod === "cod") {
            setButtonDisabled(true);
            setOrderButtonMessage("Wait for your order. You pay on delivery");
            alert("Захиалгыг хүлээн авлаа.")
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    fetchOrderDetails();  // Call the async function
 

here is mongoose schema:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./UserModel");

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: User,
    },


can we see what the logs for the getOrder are? Seems like it could be helpful in seeing if the orders are being saved properly and where the data loss is coming from

yeah sure , i updated

I believe the -_id in getOrder findById may be the problem? All the documentation I read seems to suggest that is meant for excluding a field from being selected
